# bulk node translation

Tags: nodes, i18n-l10n

We have a lot of languages on the site and a node needs to be translated in every one of them.
We create the node in English and then some people translate the content to their language. So when there is no translation available the content remains in English. The translators only have edit permissions for the nodes in there language.
To not have to give them more access we create the nodes that should be translated.

Now when creating a node we have to click translate several times to create a node for every language.  I'm looking for a way to do this in one click.

One way i was thinking of this is by selecting the node to be translated and do something like the existing bulk operations to translate them.

Or by using rules to create a translation for every language when the node is created.

Anyone with experience in this field?

Comment: It might help if you described what modules/setup/etc. you're using to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the Entity translation actions module. 
https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation_actions